# Как сравнить один список с другим?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть большой список и другой большой список. Как сделать чтобы если 1(или больше) элементов из первого списка совпадали с элементами второго списка, то они удалялись из второго списка? Python

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Можно так `[x for x in list1 if x not in list2]`, только это вернет новый список

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Превратите первый список в set для быстрого поиска
Пройдите по второму списку в обратном направлении, проверяя, есть ли очередной элемент в set - если есть  - удалите.

Comment: можете показать код?

Comment: Какие именно слова непонятны? Может быть, стоит познакомиться с базовым синтаксисом?

Comment: не понял как преобразовать список в множество

Comment: просто set(alist)